# Array inside array

Tags: php, arrays, session, laravel-4

I want to put my data inside an array not on array within array,
Here's the result of `Session::all`

```
"imei": [
  {
    "imei_id": "3213",
    "item_name": "item_name"
  },
  {
    "imei_id": "3213",
    "item_name": "Dustin Bailey"
  }
]
```

This is the output of the array, after posting some data

```
"imei": [
[
  {
    "imei_id": "12312",
    "item_name": "item_name"
  },
  {
    "imei_id": "3213",
    "item_name": "item_name"
  },
  {
    "imei_id": "3123",
    "item_name": "item_name"
  }
  ]
]
```

**Code on my Controller**

```
foreach($imei as $imei_id => $imei_unit) 
{
   $items[] = array(
    'imei_id' => $imei_unit,
    'item_name' =>  $item_name,
);
}
Session::push('imei', $items);
```

Comment: Please comment on reason for down vote ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this -

```
foreach($imei as $imei_id => $imei_unit) 
{
     $item = array(
         'imei_id'   => $imei_unit,
         'item_name' => $item_name,
     );

     Session::push('imei', $item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($imei as $imei_id => $imei_unit) 
{
     $items[]['imei_id'] = $imei_unit;
     $items[]['item_name'] = $item_name;
}
```

Comment: The result is like the first one but it separates the data.